# Does $P(f(n,X)>R)\leq g(R)$ uniformly in n imply that $P(\max_{1\leq n\leq N} f(n,X)>R)\leq g(R)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that we have a real valued random variable $X$ and a nice function $f:\{1,...,N\}\times \mathbb R\to \mathbb R^+$. Suppose that we know that uniformly in $n$, we have $P(f(n,X)>R)\leq g(R)$ for some decreasing nice function $g$. Then does $P(\max_{1\leq n\leq N} f(n,X)>R)\leq g(R)$?

I know that $P(\max_{1\leq n\leq N} f(n,X)>R)=P(f(n^\ast(\omega),X)>R)$, where $n^\ast(\omega)$ is the random maximizer, where if there is more than one we make the choice of the least. We know that

$$P(f(n^\ast,X)>R)=P(f(n^\ast,X)>R|n^\ast=1)P(n^\ast=1)+...+P(f(n^\ast,X)>R|n^\ast=N)P(n^\ast=N).$$

We can simplify to

$$P(f(n^\ast,X)>R)=P(f(1,X)>R|n^\ast=1)P(n^\ast=1)+...+P(f(N,X)>R|n^\ast=N)P(n^\ast=N),$$

but here I am stuck.

Comment: I don't want to give you the answer, but have you considered the claim being false?

Comment: @E-A Yes. I would also like to see a counterexample that it is false

Comment: I will give you a hint: Say X is a real valued random variable, and it has N digits all chosen i.i.d...